# Simple redirect with Redirectee doesn't work

Tags: redirects, 404, redirection

In my Templates Global Preferences I've set the 404 page to go to pages/404.html template.
In that template is a redirect to the 404 page:

```
{exp:redirectee:redirect status="404" url="/404/"}
```

It doesn't work, instead it shows a blank page, as if that tag wasn't in the template.

I have used the redirectee redirect on another template on the same site, and it works!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the redirectee plugin use the native PHP header function which not support the 404 code. In fact it is a little bit strange to send a 404 with the header. Therefor you have to use a 302 code, the 404 page will send a 404 code on his page.

As for redirecting with the 404 code, you have the think of this QA:

- User: Hey, do you have anything for me at this URI webserver?
- Webserver: Yes, I do, it's a 'PHP' page. It'll tell you what the
  response code is
- PHP: Hey, OMG 404!!!!!!!
- Webserver: Well crap, the 
  404 page people have already gone home, so I'll just send along
  whatever PHP gave me

I just uploaded a new version of the Redirectee with a check on this problem.